# Changing decimal places on php poll result

Tags: php, decimal

I have the following piece of code for a very simple PHP polling script

```
<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Yes:</td>
    <td><img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes+$maybe),3)); ?>'
height='20'> <?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes+$maybe),3)); ?>% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No:</td>
    <td><img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes+$maybe),3)); ?>'
height='20'> <?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes+$maybe),3)); ?>% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Maybe:</td>
    <td><img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($maybe/($no+$yes+$maybe),3)); ?>'
height='20'> <?php echo(100*round($maybe/($no+$yes+$maybe),3)); ?>% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

However, if they all have an equal amount of votes, i get a result like 33.333333333%. How do i reduce this to only one decimal place?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ps. my php skills are shocking, so the simpler the answer the better please!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using [round](http://php.net/round) after you have multiplied by 100, not before.

```
<?php echo round(($no/($no+$yes+$maybe) * 100 ),1) ; ?>
```

Your code could also be simplified a little, to something like this

```
<?php
$votecount = $no+$yes+$maybe;
$yespercentage = round($yes / $votecount * 100,1);
$nopercentage =  round($no / $votecount * 100,1);
$maybepercentage =  round($maybe / $votecount * 100,1);
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Yes:</td>
    <td><img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo $yespercentage; ?>'
height='20'> <?php echo $yespercentage; ?>% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No:</td>
    <td><img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo $nopercentage; ?>'
height='20'> <?php echo $nopercentage; ?>% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Maybe:</td>
    <td><img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo $maybepercentage; ?>'
height='20'> <?php echo $maybepercentage; ?>% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, Ive not been very clear, the actual code is:

<p> <?php echo round(($james/($angus+$beth+$chris+$claire+$danb+$dans+$gavin+$graham+$james+$lauren+$matt+$rob+$shaun+$simon),14)); ?>% <p/>

Could you edit this to be only one decimal place??

Comment: hmmm, it doesnt seem to have worked. I thought the 14 was there to create the average between the 14 options?

Comment: the second parameter is the amount of digits. Your brackets are at the wrong place aswell. It should be `<?php echo round(($james/($angus+$beth+$chris+$claire+$danb+$dans+$gavin+$graham+$james+$la‌​uren+$matt+$rob+$shaun+$simon)),14); ?>%`

Answer (score 0):

PHP's Math library has a round method:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

So in this case, you would call round on the result and specify you want it to one decimal place:

```
$rounded_value = round($result,1);
```

The first argument is the value you want to round, the second is the number of decimal places - you can leave it blank or use 0 if you want no decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

have you try using `number_format()` ? like `$maybepercentage =  number_format(round($maybe / $votecount * 100,1),1);` eg:

```
$maybepercentage =  number_format(round(90 / 120* 100,1),1);
echo $maybepercentage;
```

the result will become `75.0`